# combinations for numbers 0 to 40

Tags: combinations

I would like to know all possible combinations from 0-40 in sets of 2. So for example:

1 / 1 - 
1 / 2 -
1 / 3 -
1 / 4 -
1 / 5 -
1 / 6 -
1 / 7 -
1 / 8 -
1 / 9 - 
1 / 10

All the way to 40 and all possible combinations.

Cheers.

Comment: Heard about for-loops?!

Comment: Build a square table with rows from 1..40 and columns from 1..40. Each cell represents a valid combination, and taken together, they represent all valid combinations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In haskell:

```
[(x, y) | x <- [1..40], y <- [1..40]]
```

In other languages you should probably look at for-loops: (this is C#)

```
Tuple<int, int>[,] things = new Tuple<int, int>[40,40];
for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 40; j++)
    {
        things[i,j] = Tuple.Create(i+1,j+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers, is this meant to to in excel?

Comment: @daniel: You didn't ask for Excel, did you?

Comment: @daniel **Haskell** not **Excel**

Comment: Do you know the formula in excel?

Comment: @daniel Excel is WYSIWYG, my tip would be to use [this](https://www.google.com) to search for your answer